# disable autofocus feature in iPhone 3G S

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to disable the auto focus feature in the iPhone 3G S.

How i can do it programmatically?

I used custom  UIImagePickerController for my camera application. I don't need this feature in my application.

please help me.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should work for what you want:

```
NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devices];
NSError *error;
for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices) {
    if (([device hasMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]) && 
        ([device position] == AVCaptureDevicePositionBack) ) {
        [device lockForConfiguration:&error];
         if ([device isFocusModeSupported:AVCaptureFocusModeLocked]) {
         device.focusMode = AVCaptureFocusModeLocked;
         NSLog(@"Focus locked");
         }

        [device unlockForConfiguration];
    }
}
```

Seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402461/iphone-ios-4-3-camera-focus-square-removeable-programatically)!

Answer (score 0):

Generally your application shouldn't be changing this setting, if your users don't want to use the auto-focus then they can disable it, but your app shouldn't make that choice for them.

Is there a good reason why you would need to control that? Does it interfere with your desired functionality in some way?

Comment: This is the client requirement. So i need to disable that.