# IPhone iOS 4.3 camera focus square - removeable programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, focus, camera

Since my friend updated his iPhone iOS to 4.3 there's a small square which appears every time he takes a picture with the camera.
We're developing an app that uses the camera and would like to remove this annoying square. I didn't find anything about it in Apple's UIImagePickerController documentation.
The square didn't exist in former iOS versions.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to try to lock the focus to disable auto-focus.  Here is a sample code:

```
    NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devices];
    NSError *error;
    for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices) {
        if (([device hasMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]) && 
            ([device position] == AVCaptureDevicePositionBack) ) {
            [device lockForConfiguration:&error];
             if ([device isFocusModeSupported:AVCaptureFocusModeLocked]) {
             device.focusMode = AVCaptureFocusModeLocked;
             NSLog(@"Focus locked");
             }

            [device unlockForConfiguration];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting the `.showsCameraControls` property of your picker controller to `NO` should remove the focus square (it did pre 4.3, I don't think anything has changed), but the downside is you'll need to provide your own controls (to take photos, etc). It's all or nothing I'm afraid!

Comment: I already set the showsCameraControls property to NO. I guess thats why on lower iOS versions I don't see this square (and have no other buttons as well), but on 4.3 it seems like it doesn't help...

Comment: I'd file a bug to Apple, but in the meantime the only way round it is going to be to use the AVFoundation class, bypassing the UIImagePickerController entirely: bit of a pain, I know... :(

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom overlay and default overlay will not display. You can make your overlay can be completely empty.

Comment: that doesn't help in iOS7