# stop autofocusing in uiimagepickerviewcontroller

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller

How to stop the auto focusing in `UIimagepickercontroller` camera in iPhone sdk?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IPhone iOS 4.3 camera focus square - removeable programatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402461/iphone-ios-4-3-camera-focus-square-removeable-programatically)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You may want to try to lock the focus to disable auto-focus. Here is a sample code:

```
 NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devices];
    NSError *error;
    for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices) {
        if (([device hasMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]) && 
            ([device position] == AVCaptureDevicePositionBack) ) {
            [device lockForConfiguration:&error];
             if ([device isFocusModeSupported:AVCaptureFocusModeLocked]) {
             device.focusMode = AVCaptureFocusModeLocked;
             NSLog(@"Focus locked");
             }

            [device unlockForConfiguration];
        }
    }
```

Also you can try setting the `.showsCameraControls` property of your picker controller to NO should remove the focus square (it did pre 4.3, I don't think anything has changed), but the downside is you'll need to provide your own controls (to take photos, etc).

Comment: Down voted, copied already existing answer. Here it's http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402461/iphone-ios-4-3-camera-focus-square-removeable-programatically

Comment: This also doesn't work - you can't mix AVCaptureDevice API's while using UIImagePicker.

If you want to lock the focus you have to use AVCaptureDevice (and use it all the way). If you simply call the above functions after presenting the UIimagepickercontroller - it will have no effect on the focus of the camera. At least it has never ever worked in any iOS version when I have tried it.

Answer (score 0):

set `showsCameraControls` to `NO` like bellow..

```
picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
```

Also see another answer from this link [iphone-ios-4-3-camera-focus-square-removeable-programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402461/iphone-ios-4-3-camera-focus-square-removeable-programatically)